# Dynamic data contracts in WCF

Tags: wcf, soa, dto

There are some pain points around transmitting entities between a client and a WCF service.

- Defeating lazy loading by serializing all properties
- Serialized data can be unecessarily bloated
- Some coupling between UI and business layer

One way to address these issues is to transmit DTOs instead of entities but I am aware that this technique has its own set of caveats (the biggest one I am aware of is the typing required to maintain these function-specific DTOs).

I think it would be great if the service implementation could generate these DTOs dynamically and [this appears to be possible](http://www.basarat.com/2011/04/how-wcf-will-deal-will-dynamic.html).  Unfortunately, it looks like the contract would be loosely defined on the client side (i.e. "object") and that smells like a possible risk.

Is it advisable to use dynamic DTOs in this fashion or is there another way to use DTOs without creating/maintaining classes for each one?

I think the holy grail would be where the implementation dynamically generates DTOs but the client sees well-defined contracts.  I'm guessing this isn't possible with WCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue is what are you going to generate them from? You have to have some description somewhere of what the data you want to transmit looks like. If all you have is the domain objects then you end up in a similar position of transmitting the data that you would of via the domain object.

One of the key things the DTO enables is decoupling so you can evolve your domain objects without breaking the consumers of your service accidently. If you dynamically generate the DTOs then you will cascade the changes - unless you view the dynamic creation as a one-off exercise to get you started with a DTO

Answer (score 1):

DTO is data contract as any other and must be defined. When you choose to go with DTOs you are adding a layer of complexity which you have to maintain. There are tools which can help you with mapping between domain objects and DTOs (like AutoMapper) but your responsibility is to define what DTO should transfer - that is something which can hardly be done automatically. Even with automated tool you will still have to maintain some definition of DTOs which will be used to generate code.